# Block or redirect an url with some ampersands

Tags: .htaccess

Need to redirect or block this url.

> home/?option=com_content&task=view&id=49&Itemid=78

None solutions worked so far. Tried also this

```
RewriteRule ^home/?option=com_content&task=view&id=49&Itemid=78$ - [F]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following Rule to block the Url :

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /home/\?option=com_content&task=view&id=49&Itemid=78 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Or try this, if you want to redirect the url to hompage :

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /home/\?option=com_content&task=view&id=49&Itemid=78 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [R,L]
```